# Can i delete a span of items in an array.?

Tags: arrays, ruby, nested

Say i have an array of times:

```
daily_time_chunks = [ ['8:30','9:00'], 
                ['9:00','9:30'], 
                ['9:30','10:00'], 
                ['10:00','10:30'], 
                ['10:30','11:00'], 
                ['11:00','11:30'], 
                ['11:30','12:00'], 
                ['1:00','1:30'] ]
```

Is there a way to delete spans in this array. If 9:00 matched my specification for a start time and 11:00 matched my other specification for an end time, can i delete the nested array starting with the 9:00, the nested array ending with 11:00 and all the nested arrays in between them?

Answer (score 1):

I would start with something like this:

```
daily_time_chunks.delete_if do |time_slot| 
  ('09:00'..'11:00').cover?(time_slot.first.rjust(5, '0'))
end
#=> [["8:30","9:00"],["11:30","12:00"],["1:00","1:30"]]
```

Because this is based on string comparisons it is important to *normalize* the input time from `9:00` to `09:00` and to normalize the existing entries in the array before checking the condition: (`rjust(5, '0')` prepends `0` to entries that are too short).

Comment: From the description, I'd say that you deleted one array too many.

Comment: Reading the question again I am not sure if he wants to keep or remove the array with the `11:00`. If he wants to keep it, just change the range to exclude the ending - like this `('09:00'...'11:00')` (note the three dots).

Answer (score 0):

This code is a bit verbose, but it should be more robust than just checking the first or the last element.

It :

- converts a time to minutes (e.g. `'11:30'` to `690`)
- converts the time spans to an integer range (`['8:30','9:00']` to `510..540`)
- removes any time spans which overlaps `'9:00', '11:00'` during at least one minute.
- leaves spans which only touch `'9:00', '11:00'`. `["8:30", "9:00"], ["11:00", "11:30"]` are left in the array.

---

```
def time_to_minutes(hhmm)
  h, m = hhmm.split(':').map(&:to_i)
  h * 60 + m
end

def to_minute_range(hhmm1, hhmm2)
  (time_to_minutes(hhmm1)..time_to_minutes(hhmm2))
end

def strict_overlap?(range1, range2)
  range1.min < range2.max && range2.min < range1.max
end

to_delete = to_minute_range('9:00', '11:00')

p daily_time_chunks.reject{|times| strict_overlap?(to_minute_range(*times), to_delete)}
# [["8:30", "9:00"], ["11:00", "11:30"], ["11:30", "12:00"], ["1:00", "1:30"]]
```

With `'8:55', '11:05'`, it outputs:

```
[["11:30", "12:00"], ["1:00", "1:30"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could [`transpose`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Array.html#method-i-transpose) your nested array, find the index of the start and end elements, and then [`slice!`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Array.html#method-i-slice-21) out everything in that range. Like this:

```
def filter_out(chunks, start_time, end_time)
  new_chunks = chunks.transpose

  start_index, end_index = [start_time, end_time].map do |t|
    new_chunks.shift.index(t)
  end

  chunks.slice!(start_index, end_index)
  chunks
end

filter_out(daily_time_chunks, "9:00", "11:00")
#=> [["8:30", "9:00"], ["11:00", "11:30"], ["11:30", "12:00"], ["1:00", "1:30"]]
```

This assumes that your nested array is sorted, and that the time you are filtering on always matches the span times (e.g. if you need to filter everything between "9:25" and "11:10", then this approach won't work)

Answer (score 0):

You could use Ruby's [flip-flop](http://nithinbekal.com/posts/ruby-flip-flop/) operator here.

```
chunks = [[ '8:30', '9:00'], [ '9:00', '9:30'], [ '9:30','10:00'], ['10:00','10:30'],
          ['10:30','11:00'], ['11:00','11:30'], ['11:30','12:00'], [ '1:00', '1:30']]

chunks.reject { |s,e| s=='9:00'..e=='11:00' ? true : false }
  #=> [["8:30", "9:00"], ["11:00", "11:30"], ["11:30", "12:00"], ["1:00", "1:30"]]
```

Note that one cannot write

```
chunks.reject { |s,e| s=='9:00'..e=='11:00' }
  #=> ArgumentError: bad value for range
```